# how to insert dynamic multiple rows textboxes generated value in a variable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying insert dynamic multiple rows textboxes generated value in a variable to send it through ajax json to server side.
Code for generating multiple dynamic values.

```
$('#btnASize').click(function() {
  var sizerangeMin = "<input type='text' ID='SizeMin' value='2.00' />";
  var ToleranceMin = "<input type='text' ID='TolMin'+i value='1' />";
  var ToleranceMax = "<input type='text' ID='TolMax'+i value='1' />";
  var markup = "<tr><td>" + sizerangeMin + "</td><td>" + ToleranceMin + "</td><td>" + ToleranceMax + "</td></tr>";
  $("#WireDimTbl tbody").append(markup);
});

$('#btnASizeR').click(function() {
  var sizerangeMin = "<input type='text' ID='SizeMin' value='2.00' />";
  var sizerangeMax = "<input type='text' ID='SizeMax' value='3.00' />";
  var ToleranceMin = "<input type='text' ID='TolMin' value='1' />";
  var ToleranceMax = "<input type='text' ID='TolMax' value='1' />";
  var markup = "<tr><td>" + sizerangeMin + "</td><td>" + sizerangeMax + "</td><td>" + ToleranceMin + "</td><td>" + ToleranceMax + "</td></tr>";
  $("#WireDimTbl tbody").append(markup);
});

$('#btnWdDelete').click(function() {
  $("#WireDimTbl tbody>tr:last").remove();
})
```

Ajax code for sending data

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(document).on("click", "[id*=btnFrmSubmit]", function() {
            var user = {};
            user.PRODUCT_ID = 1;
            user.TDC_NO = $("[id*=Tdc_No]").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TDC.aspx/SaveFrmDetails",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    user: user
                })
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    alert("Data has been added successfully.");
                    window.location.reload();
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the above ajax method i want to store values of dynamically generated multiple  textboxes value in "var user" to send it through ajax method to server side but not getting any idea how to achieve it i have shown in above code only for a particular input box

```
"<th class='text-center'>TDC No.</th>" +
                        "<th><input id='Tdc_No' type='text' value='7y'/></th>".
```

how to achieve it for multiple dynamically generated input textboxes.
Code at server side i am just showing few items how am i doing.

```
public class User
{
    public decimal PRODUCT_ID { get; set; }
    public string TDC_NO { get; set; }
    .
    .
}

[WebMethod]    
    public static void SaveFrmDetails(User user)
{
 string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["condb"].ConnectionString;
 using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO TDC_PRODUCT1(TDC_NO) VALUES (:TDC_NO)",con)
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":TDC_NO", user.TDC_NO);
 cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you know what a loop does?do you know array manipulations?how to store a value in a variable?how to get a value from a input?

Comment: is that worked for you ??? have you tried ?

Comment: @PranayRana it's working but how to pass it to server side and  then how to store in db

Comment: @hari - for server side if you are passing json object , than server side method should have parameter object with that same strucutre ...once you receive it you can able to store it in DB...what are you having on sever side ???  and let me know output of your $("#WireDimTbl tbody").children( ":input" ).serializeArray(); statement

Comment: @PranayRana i have updated server side part. in case of dynamic text boxes how would i define  parameter object with same strucutre  at server side and how would i store in db could you guide.

Comment: can you pleas paste output of this $("#WireDimTbl tbody").children( ":input" ).serializeArray();

Comment: @PranayRana currently cheking it is showing blank. fields = []

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161698/discussion-between-hari-and-pranay-rana).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this , make use of [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and [find()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert(JSON.stringify($("#WireDimTbl tbody").find(":input").serializeArray()));
});
```

jsfiddle working : https://jsfiddle.net/pranayamr/odja5te0/