# how to send multiple value from client to server using ajax json

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json

I'm trying to send multiple data from client to server using ajax json.
case First: when i send my form inputs data from client to server it was going well.
case second:now one modification done in my form and i am generating dynamic multiple rows with textboxes .and it's values should also pass using same ajax method but my try go in vain so any idea would be appreciated.
Refer below article for more coding part details about this question.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920685/how-to-insert-dynamic-multiple-rows-textboxes-generated-value-in-a-variable?noredirect=1#comment82811853_47920685)

I am trying like this

```
 $(document).on("click", "[id*=btnFrmSubmit]", function () {          
            alert("hi");
            var fields = $("#WireDimTbl tbody").find(":input").serializeArray();
            var user = {};
            user.PRODUCT_ID = 1;
            user.TDC_NO = $("[id*=Tdc_No]").val();
            user.REVISION = $("#Revision").text();
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TDC.aspx/SaveFrmDetails",                
                data: JSON.stringify({ user: user,fields:fields}),
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("Data has been added successfully.");
                    window.location.reload();
                },                
                error: function (response) { alert(response.responseText); }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

At Sever side  part what modification should be done.how would i define parameter object with same strucutre at server side and how would i store in db.

Comment: which technology you are using in `server` side ?

Comment: @Njdhv c# asp.net

Comment: See this [example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-AJAX-call-with-parameters-example-Send-parameters-to-WebMethod-in-jQuery-AJAX-POST-call.aspx). I hope this will guide you.

Comment: @Njdhv i got your point if you see my example i am also trying like this.But how to pass dynamic multiple rows with textboxes  values through ajax json.

Comment: Try `data: {myData: JSON.stringify({ user: user,fields:fields})`, and your server side should be something like `SaveFrmDetails(string myData)`

Comment: @MUT IT's not working .how would i define parameter object with same strucutre at server side.

Comment: @hari, share `SaveFrmDetails` function.

Comment: @MUT previously i was sending these data in SaveFrmDetails method  [WebMethod]    
     and definedpublic static void SaveFrmDetails(User user,string byteData, string imageName, string contentType, string byteData1, string imageName1, string contentType1) parameter object with same strucutre at server side.u can check in my hyperlink item.

Comment: @hari, lets discuss this in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161800/discussion-between-mut-and-hari)